# Is there an ideal scoring term for determining two numbers?

Tags: optimization

Let's say I have a known vector of two numbers: `c(A,B)`

Is there a scoring term, or a *combination of scoring terms*, that can measure the **unique** closeness of a random vector `c(a,b)` to the known vector? In other words, is there a scoring term that can be used to determine that `a` is very close to `A` AND that `b` is very close to `B`?

Heres an example of a scoring term, $S$, I thought of:

$$S = \lvert a - A \rvert + \lvert b - B \rvert$$

It's not ideal because if our vector is `c(1,5)`, then the vectors `c(2,4)` and `c(0,4)` would give the same scoring metric value of $2$. I would like the scoring metric to give me more information. Such as, for this example, $a$ is approaching $A$ from above for `c(2,4)`and $a$ is approaching $A$ from below for `c(0,4)`.

I would also be interested to see how a scoring term, or combination of scoring terms, could be generalized to a vector of length $n$.

Comment: In your example, if $(A,B) = (5,1)$, then wouldn't you have $c(5,1)=0$ and $c(1,5)=4+4=8$?

Comment: There is no best answer until you define your objective.  You are probably interested in a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), which measures the distance between points.  Yours is called the Manhattan metric.  Théophile gives the Euclidean metric.  Neither is better until you define the objective.

Comment: Your call for a unique value emphasizes the need to say what you want.  Why shouldn't $(0,4)$ and $(2,4)$ be the same distance from $(1,5)$.  Any rotationally symmetric metric will do that.  Which do you want to be closer? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A natural choice would be the Euclidean distance to $(A,B)$:
$$c(a,b) = \sqrt{(a-A)^2+(b-B)^2}.$$
This generalizes to $n$ dimensions.